# Applying different colorschemes to different windows

Tags: vim

I want to used different colorschemes for different filetypes and I added the following code in my .vimrc

```
function SetColorScheme ()
  if &filetype != "vo_base"
    colorscheme desertEx 
  endif
endfunction 
au WinEnter * call SetColorScheme()
```

This works fine with one issue.

If I open a .otl file, say todo.otl (vo_base), and then open another file, say example.xml, using :sp the colorscheme desertEx does not get applied to the second window (the one having example.xml).

If I use BufEnter instead of WinEnter than desertEx gets applied to both the windows.

Is there a way to make sure that when I open a window with :sp the above function (a) runs, and (b) runs only for that particular window and not all the windows in the current session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there's no way to do that. There can be only one active colorscheme at the same time in vim.

Answer (score 1):

Something that comes to mind is to create a color scheme that directly points to the low-level syntax groups in the Vim syntax files.

Take for instance c.vim for the C programming language. You will find for instance syntax hightlighting groups such as: cStatement, cLabel, cConditional, cType.. etc.

Take python.vim and you will find pythonDefStatement, pythonFunction, pythonConditional, etc..

So, if you want to use different color schemes for C code and python, you would copy the two original color schemes to ~/.vim/colors/mycolorscheme.vim and edit them to point to the low-level syntax groups instead of the generic high level groups such as Comment, Constant, Error, Identifier, etc. that are found in many available color schemes.

Note that you would probably want keep a default stanza of 'highlight' statements on top of these other two to take care of syntax highlighting for files that contain neither C nor python code.

To clarify, you could edit the celebrated 'Hello World' code and issue the following from the Vim command line:

```
:hi cInclude ctermfg=cyan guifg=cyan
```

You have not changed color schemes, other files displayed in other windows or tabs are unaffected, and yet the '#include' is now displayed in a different color.

Unless you absolutely need the feature, I would advise against it, because it pretty much breaks Vim's syntax highlighting. Besides, it will require significant work to convert the existing ':hi' statements comprised in the original color schemes because there are usually many low-level syntax highlighting groups.

A somewhat better approach might be to link the language-specific low level groups to high-level groups that are also specific to each language. This would help keep the custom color scheme file reasonably small, but requires additional inventory work.